# Google Analytics: Maximum DAU before reaching 10M monthly hit limit

Tags: google-analytics

Given that Google Analytics specifies a maximum of 10M hits per month on a standard free account, that seems to imply that as soon as a website gains more than 328K daily active users you will exceed your allowed quota.

This generously assumes that each user only visits the site once per day, and also only generates a single hit during that session.

I just want to sanity check this fact and make sure I'm not missing something obvious.

Also, does anyone have any suggestions for effectively using google analytics when the DAUs exceed 328K?

If I bundle a few dimensions together like this:

```
ga('set', {
  dimension1: 'f',
  dimension2: 'o',
  dimension3: 'o',
});
```

and then do a single post with:

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

will this count as a single hit or 3 individuals hits (as far as my limit is concerned)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So some background on the limit, the 10M limit is a soft limit, but if you keep exceeding the 10M hit limit, you might lose data. You can check your current hit amount in the settings for the property. If you are exceeding the 10m limit, I would suggest, short of buying GA360, looking into splitting your site into sections in multiple properties or try to decrease the number of hits.

Now, for your other question, it will count as one hit. This is because "set" does not send any information to GA, only the "send" will hit GA.

Comment: So my estimation of a max user base of 320K DAUs is accurate?

Comment: I think you can get a more accurate estimate by looking at your current your current 30 day hit amount, then look at your 30 day user amount. Divide the two to get hits per user, and use that to calculate how many users will max out your 30 day 10M limit.